# DateTime parsing exception in java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm developing my mobile app with API. Binding datetime gives me error
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-12-16T00:00:00+03:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19. Please help me format this weird date

```
fun formatDateOfReview(dateOfReview: String?): String? {
    val localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(dateOfReview)
    return localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"))
}
```

Comment: @jhamon that pattern is not used to parse the input but rather to format it as date only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
2022-12-16T00:00:00+03:00
```

That is [a combined date-time with a time zone in ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations).

```
LocalDateTime.parse(dateOfReview)
```

`LocalDateTime` [is "A date-time **without a time-zone** in the ISO-8601 calendar system"](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDateTime) (emphasis added).

Please [use `OffsetDateTime`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/OffsetDateTime) instead.

Comment: Good answer. Unfortunately, that Wikipedia article uses the words “time zone” where it should use “offset”. The `+03:00` is an offset from UTC, not a time zone. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region, as decided by their politicians. The time zone has a name in the format of continent/region, such as `Africa/Nairobi`, `Europe/Helsinki`, and `Indian/Mayotte`.